# Modify eloquent subquery dynamically to filter dates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query and it works correctly. The only thing, when I go to filter I don't know how to add a new where.

```php
$parts = Part::query()
    ->select(
        'parts.employee_id',
        'parts.date_of_part',
        DB::raw('SUM(parts.time) AS day_total_time')
    )
    ->groupBy('parts.date_of_part', 'parts.employee_id');

$holidays = Holiday::query()
    ->select(
        'holidays.employee_id',
        'holidays.date_of_holiday',
        DB::raw('SUM(holidays.time) AS total_holidays_time')
    )
    ->groupBy('holidays.employee_id');

return User::query()
    ->select(
        'users.name',
        DB::raw('SUM(works.day_total_time) AS parts_sum_time'),
        DB::raw('vacaciones.total_holidays_time AS holidays_sum_time')
    )
    ->JoinSub(
        $parts,
        'works',
        function (JoinClause $join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'partes.employee_id');
        }
    )
    ->leftJoinSub(
        $holidays,
        'vacaciones',
        function (JoinClause $join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'vacaciones.employee_id');
        }
    )
    ->groupBy('users.id');
```

If I do the following, it adds the where to the main query and I'm interested in doing it inside the subqueries.

```php
fn(Builder $query, $date): Builder => $query
   ->whereDate('works.date_of_part', '=', $date)
   ->whereDate('calendar.date_of_holiday', '=', $date)
```

How could I add the where inside each JoinSub?

Comment: I know this has nohing to do with your question, but pease, do follow PSR standards, you either wrap as expected, or your break each line into new lines, else it is very unreadable

Comment: You can modify each `JoinClause` by accessing the Builder's (`$query`) public `$joins` property. For example `$query->joins[0]->whereDate(....)`. I've posted a more detailed answer below.

Comment: I've just noticed there is a catch with my approach. This **does not work** for `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. It first needs to be converted to `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` with the `toBase()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you **sure** this query works? The aliases seem to be wrong in the first join.

```php
->JoinSub(
    $parts,
    'works',
    function (JoinClause $join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'partes.employee_id'); # <- should be works.employee_id
    }
)
```

If you want to add those conditions inside the join, you can just add them to the closure.

```php
->JoinSub(
    $parts,
    'works',
    function (JoinClause $join) use ($date) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'works.employee_id')
             ->whereDate('works.date_of_part', '=', $date);
    }
)
```

---

However if for some reason you want to edit the query AFTER it's returned, it's not as intuitive.

Let's say your code is returned by a `getQuery()` function.

```php
function getQuery(): Builder
{
    $parts = Part::query()->...;

    $holidays = Holiday::query()->...;

    return User::query()->...;
}
```

And you want to edit the join clause of whatever is returned here. You **can** do it, by directly accessing the base query builder's `join` property, but **you need to be aware of the order they are in** and **the correct alias**. There's no magic way of "accessing a specific join".

```php
$query = getQuery();

$joins = $query->toBase()->joins // array of JoinClause objects
$joins[0]->whereDate('works.date_of_part', $date); // alter first join (works)

// You can see this condition is applied when dumping the value $query->toSql()
$query->get();
```

Your second `whereDate` references a `calendar` table that is nowhere to be seen, so I expect it would fail.